# why preview window showing different screen and real device different?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout, preview

I am developing a new app and preview showing the different UI in android studio and real device showing different UI is different how can show screen in a real device the same as in the preview.
as you can see from the real device skip text is missing

below my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vector_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/vectors_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/doctor_appointment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.442"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.233" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_doct"
        android:layout_width="272dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/search_doct"
        android:textAppearance="@style/search_doct"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/some_id"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.697"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/vector_1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/get_list_of"
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_doct"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="@string/get_list_of"
        android:textAppearance="@style/get_list_of"
        />



    <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.477"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801"
        app:piv_animationType="scale"
        app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
        app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
        app:piv_selectedColor="@color/gray_50"
        app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/gray_300"
        app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager"
        attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
        attrs:piv_radius="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="636dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/skip"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.537"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below preview windows in android studio

[image: preview screen]

[image: real device ui]

I want to know where exactly I am making mistakes any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.93" instead of margin top for  @+id/skip

Comment: you mean I have to remove margin top right kelvin

Comment: Yes I think that's what causing the problem .

Comment: @kelvin if I remove margin top skip showing on the top not down

Comment: Did you add vertical bias ??

Comment: @kelvin yes I have added

Comment: @Kelvin yes I have added skip showing on the top of the screen after removing margin top

Comment: app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
add this too

Comment: what about Search Doctors text how can I position that text above get list of doctor

Comment: @kelvin what about Search Doctors text how can I position that text above get list of doctor

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was to use fixed size on your views and on your margins, because different phones got different screen size, you may find your preview layout looking god while on a real device it will look totally different.

**You can fix this by using constraint Layout [percentage](https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/04/percentage-width/height-using-constraint-layout) like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vector_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/some_id"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tasks_icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_doct"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vector_1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_doct"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="search_doct"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/get_list_of"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/some_id" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/get_list_of"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:text="get_list_of"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_doct" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"

    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/skip"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/get_list_of" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vector_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pageIndicatorView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this:

[image]